# AWS write to S3 bucket in prediction calling a batch job

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

When i invoke the endpoint/batch job in sagemaker deployed with a custom container i want to store some information inside S3.
For example, in this image 
[image]

In the "Deployment/Hosting" i want to put some objects inside the S3 container and not only reading the /opt/model

For example [BYO container R](https://scriptexampler.notebook.us-west-2.sagemaker.aws/examples/preview?example_id=%2Fhome%2Fec2-user%2Fsample-notebooks%2Fr_examples%2Fr_byo_r_algo_hpo%2Ftune_r_bring_your_own.ipynb)

In the plumber.R function i would like to:

```
function(req) {

    # Setup locations
    prefix <- '/opt/ml'
    model_path <- paste(prefix, 'model', sep='/')

    # Bring in model file and factor levels
    load(paste(model_path, 'mars_model.RData', sep='/'))

    # Read in data
    conn <- textConnection(gsub('\\\\n', '\n', req$postBody))
    data <- read.csv(conn)
    close(conn)

    # Convert input to model matrix
    scoring_X <- model.matrix(~., data, xlev=factor_levels)

    ####
    SAVE OBJECT IN S3
    #####


    # Return prediction
    return(paste(predict(mars_model, scoring_X, row.names=FALSE), collapse=','))}
```

How can i achieve this? Using aws.s3 connecting to the container or with other techniques?

EDIT: The aws.s3 solution to connect directly inside the container seems not working

Comment: You'll need to provide more information before I can answer this question. Please provide the code where you declare the model or processing job.
It's not good practice to write directly into s3 from a container. Instead you should use the input and output channels, aka opt/ml/output. 
This is the 'local' directory of your container; if declared properly, sagemaker will look for your output file there, and then move to a target location in s3.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Amazon S3 from SageMaker is a viable option, and feasible. To enable that, you need to make sure that you have a route to S3 from your VPC, and that the SageMaker role, has required permissions.

If you are experiencing failures in calling S3, you can post specific exceptions, but as far as design goes, the answer here is that its a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS SDK for the programming language you are using in your container. It's important to note that the SageMaker endpoint runs inside an Amazon SageMaker VPC, and you might need the necessary IAM roles to interact with other AWS services like S3.
Here is an example code to do this

```
# Define your S3 bucket and object key
s3_bucket <- "your-s3-bucket"
object_key <- "path/to/your/object"

# Your logic to save the object
your_object <- "Your data to save"
writeLines(your_object, "/tmp/your_object.txt")

# Upload the object to S3
put_object(file = "/tmp/your_object.txt",
       object = object_key,
       bucket = s3_bucket)
```

Replace "your-s3-bucket" and "path/to/your/object" with your S3 bucket and object key.